Is this sentence correct ? ( use of but)
"It is raining."
"It is just a little."
Combined as "It is raining, but just a little,".
Does the word " is " apply to both parts ( raining and just a little), making the structure parallel because both phrases share the same word. Is this construction indeed parallel? Or It's just a silly sentence.
It's drizzling or It's just a light rain is fine I think.
However, I want to say like " It's starting to rain( but not yet realized if it's gonna be heavy or light) but just a little. ( realized that it's just a light rain)
Since I'm not native, I can't tell if the sentence is correct.
"It's starting to rain but just a little."

That sentence is fine.

Is it parallel ? Is my explanation correct ?

I don’t understand your explanation. And if there’s any parallelism, it’s between It’s raining and It’s [only] raining a little.

No, it is not parallel. But you are correct that [it is raining] is the semantic anchor for the second clause.

So, my understanding is wrong about ( raining and just a little ) sharing the word " is " ? If it's not parallel, that sentence is wrong ?

If you don't know whether the rain will become heavy, you can say "It's just starting to rain."  and leave it at that. "just" there indicates a few drops are falling.

The sentence is not ungrammatical.  But it does not express the idea you have described, that you do not know if the rain will become heavier.

What does "It's starting to rain( but not yet realized if it's gonna be heavy or light) but just a little. ( realized that it's just a light rain)" mean? Are you realising halfway through the sentence that it's only light rain? Language learning normally assumes that you don't change your mind halfway through what you're saying. Although in real life if you changed your mind (or realised it was raining lightly) you'd probably break off and say something else without worrying about it all being grammatical, e.g. "It's started to - ah it's only a shower".

I guess my real confusion is if "It is raining, but just a little." is not parallel. Why is it still grammatically correct ? I thought "but" connects two different ideas of the same structure.

But the utterance "It is just a little" is not "grammatically correct". Also, it's not even idiomatically acceptable if uncontracted, except possibly with heavy stress on is, when contradicting someone who's just claimed it's not raining. Compare "I am a little" (not a valid standalone sentence, but idiomatically fine in a conversational context as a reply to "Are you cold?").

What do you mean by "parallel"?  Please cite a grammatical text that defines this word so we can understand what you mean by it.  Where are you finding it?  You take the high road and I'll take the low road is parallel; the coordinated clauses have the same syntactic structure.

It is raining but very lightly.   What is on either side of but  do not have the same overt structure.  But it is understood that "very lightly"  has [it is raining] as its anchor by virtue of the coordination.

I  was trying to learn how to use conjunction "but"
"And, but, either … or, etc. (coordinating conjunctions)
Coordinating conjunctions connect items which are the same grammatical type, e.g. words, phrases, clauses. The most common coordinating conjunctions are and, or, but."
from this website: [link] (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions?q=Conjunctions)
like here it says same grammatical.

I think this is an example of conjunction reduction, where identical parts of the sentence can be omitted following a conjunction: "It is raining, but [it is raining] just a little." The part in square brackets is dropped because it is redundant and sounds stilted; but if it's put back in, you have the parallel construction you're looking for.

@CanadianYankee ahh that's it ! The sentence is fine but I just want to know why it's fine . I can't understand how the phrases have the same construction. It's because of conjunction reduction. thanks

Punctuation is required
A: "It is raining."
B: "It is - just a little."  (The dash could be a semi-colon or even a comma.)
"It is = "It is raining
- just a little." = it is raining just a little.
just a little is an adverbial phrase modifying "it is raining."

However, I want to say "It's starting to rain but just a little. (In the sense of the weather has not decided if the rain's going to be heavy or light)  (I can see that it's just a light rain or drizzle)

Correctly punctuated, your example is correct.
